# Which are the SPI Interface Connection PINS on this LCD?

Tags: lcd

I've found an 480x480 rgb/spi interface screen, but I don't know which pins are used for SPI. There's some crazy CTP stuff and there are some I²C or SPI connection pins (SDA, SCL, Reset). But where are all SPI pins? Or is the ctp stuff SPI because of the description (TP data line serial interface)? Which pins are used for SPI? And would it be possible to connect it with a raspberry pi like [there](https://www.instructables.com/id/Connect-LCD-to-Raspberry-Pi-Without-Breakout-Board/)? Thank you very much for your answers. [LCD pin description](https://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/Hfc43569dc8c544f49545663c7b76400fh/227451848/Hfc43569dc8c544f49545663c7b76400fh.png)

Comment: Yes, you can connect SPI devices to the Pi.  However the Pi is irrelevant to your main question.

Comment: CTP could be Capacitive Touch Panel - could this be the interface for the touch data and the SDA SCL be the image data?  The nomenclature suggests to me I2C - No MOSI MISO, SDI, SDO etc for SPI.  Without more knowledge about the device, a name even, its hard to say. Given some sort of markings or identifier: model number etc. It might be possible to track down a datasheet which will identify the purpose of the pins and how to drive the display. As @Joan has pointed out this isn't strictly an RPI problem you might have more luck on a Hardware StackExchange forum.